# how to remove \n from an array in jquery aggregated with other values

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have a array something like this `["\n robort \n \ electronic","automated machine\narm"];`

how can i remove \n from this array. so that my result will look like

`[" robort electronic","automated machine arm"]`

i'm able to remove seperate(or segregated) \n with this code

```js
var arr = ["\n", "\n roborts\n"];
var removeItem = '\n';

arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(value) {
  return value != removeItem;
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So if you already have a code that does that - what is the problem?

Comment: not so in that array 2 index are there 0 th i'm able to remove but mixed \n on 1 th index i'm not

Comment: i want to remove \n roborts\n these   2 \n

Comment: add to the question the desired output on that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map it back, and remove the newlines from each index, and filter out any that are just newlines

```js
var arr = ["\n robort \n \ electronic","automated machine\narm", "\n"];

arr = arr.filter(function(item) {
  return item !== "\n";
}).map(function(item) {
  return item.replace(/\n/g,'');
});

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery:

```js
var arr = ["\n", "\n roborts\n"].map(function(val) {
  return val.replace(/\n/g, "");
});

console.log(arr);
```

This uses [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return an array consisting of the parts of your existing array but with the newline character removed.

Comment: oops, you've pasted you code into the css bit, on the snippet.. Had me puzzled why your snippet wasn't working..  Well it is a Monday. :)

Comment: @james Donnelly, now results there showing in the snippet

Comment: @Keith haha, I was wondering why the console output wasn't showing. Well spotted!

Comment: @EaBangalore that's fixed now. I'd entered the JavaScript code into the snippet's CSS area.

Answer (score 0):

User `map()` ([Link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixvPHLy5bQAhWBro8KHamTBU4QFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.map%2F&usg=AFQjCNFR3BgbMsFUCjfoLq-2gvUn5XZw_w&sig2=LY-WmyTmxKxM6cbGG1PD5w&bvm=bv.137904068,d.c2I)) array and `replace()` function.

**Code**

```
var arr = ["\nautomated machine\narm", "\n roborts \n"];
var removeItem = /\n/g;

arr = arr.map( function(value) {
  return value.replace(removeItem, "");
});

console.log(arr);
```